# Convert string to data format

Tags: r, date

I have a large number of strings of the following format:

```
a <- "19260701"
```

I would like to convert these do the following date format:

```
1926-07-01
```

when I try:

```
as.Date(a, "%Y-%m-%d")
```

I get

```
NA
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to put the format of `a` in the function `as.Date()` :

```
 a <- "19260701"
 as.Date(a,format="%Y%m%d")
 [1] "1926-07-01"
```

Answer (score 1):

```
a<- "19260701"
library(lubridate)
ymd(a)
[1] "1926-07-01 UTC"
```